# Dynamic select usign ajax and php : Send request to method - not php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to make date selecting using ajax nad php.

Desired result is to generate proper amount of possibile days in a `<select name="selectDay">`(30/31 days or 28/29 in Feb) based on chosen month in `<select name="selectMonth">`:

[image]

And I know the way to do make it works in the "standard" way (booth PHP and JQ).

The thing is I would like to **send request** to a specyfic method rather than sending request to php script (`url: "select.php"`). And I have no idea how to do it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Where is the code you have already tried?

Comment: The question is more like: Is it possible to send ajax request to a method/function insted of php file? And if so, how to do this. Im not asking for finding error in my code - thats why I didint paste it here.

Comment: If that's the case then I would say try if it's possible if not come back and post your problem. Questions about if something is possible are off-topic  on SO

Comment: Ok. I see your point. I'll remember this for the future, thanks. BTW Like I said I had no idea how to even start. That's why I asked. Ps.  I looked for solution (before i posted the q here) but find nothing.

Comment: @SuperDJ *"Questions about if something is possible are off-topic on SO"* - complete nonsense. There are plenty of problems with this question, but that is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you could do this easily without using Ajax.

```
<form>
    <?php

        echo "<select id='month' name='month' onchange='getdays( this.value )'>";
        for( $i=1; $i < 13; $i++ ){
            echo "<option value='$i'>".date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $i, 1, date('Y') ) );
        }
        echo "</select>
        <select id='days' name='days'></select>";

    ?>
    <script>
        <?php
            $months=array();
            for( $i=1; $i < 13; $i++ ){
                $months[ $i ]=range( 1, date( 't', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $i, 1, date('Y') ) ) );
            }
            echo "var months=".json_encode( $months, true ).";";
        ?>
        function getdays( v ){

            var days=months[ v ];
            var oSel=document.getElementById('days');
            oSel.innerHTML='';

            for( var i=0; i < days.length; i++ ){
                var child=document.createElement('option');
                    child.value=days[ i ];
                    child.innerHTML=days[ i ];
                oSel.appendChild( child );  
            }
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I considered using only JS and probably I will. Thnaks